# Bypassing Firefox and IE's cross-domain policy for webfonts

Tags: internet-explorer, google-app-engine, firefox, python-2.7, webfonts

I set up a static server using Google App Engine so I can store font files, downloadable files (such as `zip`s and other application files) and for Chrome, Safari, and Opera it's working great, however with Firefox and IE I'm getting crossdomain "not allowed" errors for my webfonts. I am using a Python 2.7 runtime, and found a few methods which don't seem to work.

The first one is setting up a `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of my application (however I don't know if I'm supposed to route it/configure it for my app using a Python file or my `app.yaml` as I have yet to see an example of it) but anyways, here's my code for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-handlers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The second one is just setting up a plain `.htaccess` file (but again, I don't know how to configure/route it, so that could be the only problem). Here's that code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "false"
</IfModule>
```

But when I redeploy my static server, I still get the errors in both Firefox and IE. My experience with Python (and back-end period, really) is next to nothing, so if I did something wrong or forgot an important part, please forgive me. I can provide the code for my `app.yaml` and `main.py` if necessary (however it's really very simple). I am actively playing with the `app.yaml` to route the `crossdomain.xml` and `.htaccess`, and, while the page is found and routed correctly, it is still not displaying the webfonts in FF and IE.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serve a `crossdomain.xml` file as a static file from App Engine, add the following to your `app.yaml`, under the `handlers:` key:

```yaml
handlers:
- url: /crossdomain.xml
  static_files: static/crossdomain.xml
  upload: static/crossdomain.xml
```

There are almost certainly other `url:` entries under the `handlers:` key, of course.

The `url:` key *must* be `/crossdomain.xml`. The `static_files:` entry should be a relative path to the actual file, store it in the `static/` directory. You also *must* include an `upload:` key to tell the uploader what file is being served.

See the [Static file pattern handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers) documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I had something similar but I probably wasn't doing a small thing right. :P Which is a repercussion of my inexperience. Apparently I have to wait 19 hours to award the bounty, however, I will after that.